# AngularJS $resource GET works in Chrome but gives a 401 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angular-resource

So I've got a basic custom GET in angular using $resource

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('MyService', function($resource){
    return $resrouce('some url',
    {},
    {
       list: {method:'GET', params:{}}
    });
  });
```

I then use it like this

```
MyService.list().$promise.then(function(data){
   //do something
});
```

When I use it in Chrome (33) it works.  In firefox (10.0.2) however I get a

```
401 unauthorized
```

If I go to the url directly within firefox I get the data.

The service and my page are hosted on different boxes.  I wondered if it's got something to do with cross site protection or something?  Any thoughts?

EDIT:  I've tried enabling CORS as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28495926/779501) answer but again no help.

EDIT2: the 401 response has no body.  The headers are pretty basic...

```
HTTP/1.1: 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Content-Length: 1174
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 08:52:16 GMT
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, maybe Chrome has an Auth cookie that Firefox doesn't have?

Does the request give a response in the network tab?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I get no response body but I do get  a basic response header.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I needed to add

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Looks like it was a CORS error